# Printing whitespace in Report Writer

Tags: acumatica

In the acumatica report writer is there a method for adding whitespace in a textbox?

For example, we need to display a field that's a fixed width such as "A   B" (three spaces in between)

Using a standard &nbsp to add space doesn't work as it is being escaped.

Is there a key syntax for actually adding spaces / showing the whitespaces in the reports or preventing literal chars from being escaped when it renders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&#160;`
It's kind of nontrimable whitespace in xml format.

You have to put it right into .rpx file using some text editor, as Report designer will convert it to the `&amp;#160;`

Comment: That will work.  Editing the XML was the key.  Thanks

Comment: @Dmitry - I am trying to add `&#160;` but it is not working. And it just prints &#160; instead of whitespace.   Is there any specific setting I need to do.

Comment: Do you use report designer for that? Unfortunately, this will no work with report designer. You should open .rpx file in some text editor and put '&#160;' there.

Comment: Even that is not working.  Actually whatever changes I make in rpx file, it is not even considered. I have a field which displays Item CD and Desc where I want more space between Item CD and Desc. `=IIf([POLine.InventoryID]<>Null, Format( '{0}: {1}', [POLine.InventoryID], [POLine.TranDesc]),[POLine.TranDesc])`

Comment: That means that you probably have some report versions in your database. Customized report version is always preferred. So, you should first delete report versions from database to be able to see your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it may help someone. Change

```
=IIf([POLine.InventoryID]<>Null, Format( '{0}: {1}', 
     [POLine.InventoryID], [POLine.TranDesc]),[POLine.TranDesc])
```

to

```
=IIf([POLine.InventoryID]<>Null, Format( '{0}:{2}{2}{2}{2}{2}{2}{2}{2} {1}', 
     [POLine.InventoryID], [POLine.TranDesc]),[POLine.TranDesc],' ')
```

It should put 8 spaces.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**